# Is there an online JSON viewer/formatter that can show the path to an attribute?

Tags: javascript, json, path, pretty-print, viewer

There are a lot of good online JSON viewers where I can paste in the structure & it'll pretty-print it.. but one thing I'd find useful (for complex JSON structures) is to be able to click on an attribute and it display the JavaScript object path to get to it, e.g.

[Example image showing what I mean :)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZRv8.png)

I've not found any online (or offline) viewer that'll do this.. I don't suppose anyone knows of one?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can visit my site:  https://thisyogesh.github.io/jsonmaker/.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: That's brilliant.. just what I was after! Thank you for such a quick response :)

Answer (score -1):

You can try `JSON` Validator like [JsonLint](http://jsonlint.com/) - you simply paste a well-formatted `JSON` text and it will validate and pretty-print/display it for you. There are also extensions for Chrome (`JSON` formatter as well as `JSON` viewer) - these will give you the expand/collapse features that you desire.

Comment: JsonLint doesn't give you the dot-notation path to the attribute, nor do a lot of the Chrome extensions (plus the Chrome extensions I've found don't let you paste in arbitrary text).